# App store shows large file size after publishing

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, app-store

I have an iOS app made with Unity which its ipa is 65mb but after submitting the app store shows the size file 212mb which is almost 4 times larger than the original ipa.

I wanted to ask if you have any solutions on how to prevent this, especially if this is because the app is made with Unity.

Comment: This question is asked almost every week. It's about time somebody put a general answer that can be used to close other questions.

Answer (score 2):

First thing i would like to make clear is that the size increases is not related with which Xcode version you are using. So doesn't matter which xcode version you are using that will not affect the file size.

While we prepare new build for upload, Xcode archives the data & compresses the original files to make sure fast uploading process. So it tries to make it as small size as possible.

Now after uploading when its received at the server it decompresses the files & that is the reason why you can see size variations on the app store.

**EDIT :**

To Reduce the App size you should follow official instructions provided by Apple :
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1795/_index.html

Hope it will help to everyone.

Comment: Thanks @Mayur so is there any ways to prevent this or at least do something to decrease the size ?

Comment: @m0j1 check edited answer & accept if you feel its useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have used Xcode 8.3 for Archive, use Xcode 8.3.1 to archive as Xcode 8.3 produces 3x larger binaries.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 8.0 , so you think it is the problem? but the ipa is fine, it is only large when it is submitted to the app store.